# i am trying to initiate a popup/modal screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am developing a chat screen and i want to initiate a modal when an option on the screen is selected, i am unable t do it. kindly help me.
here is my html code where you can insert the option code.

```
<section id="demo">
    <div class="vertical-align">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-0">
                    <div class="card no-border">
                        <div id="chat" class="conv-form-wrapper">
                            <form action="" method="GET" class="hidden">
                                <select data-conv-question="Here is my features! Enjoy.">
                                    <option value="google" data-callback="googleMap">Google Map</option>
                                    <option value="bing" data-callback="dawaai">Medicine Comparison`</option>
                                </select>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The function called when data-call-back is:

```
function google(stateWrapper, ready) {
    window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/place/Agha+Khan+Hospital+Pond+No.1/@24.8935763,67.0690012,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3eb33edd90fa1943:0xd423034e388220fa!8m2!3d24.8935997!4d67.0713131");
    ready();
}

function bing(stateWrapper, ready) {
    window.open("https://dawaai.pk/");
    ready();
}
```

The code for jquery is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/autosize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.convform.js"></script>
```

as i am unable to insert the complete file for jquery i am inserting the link form where you can have the complete code for chatbot.

https://github.com/eduardotkoller/convForm

Comment: What does this question have to do with PHP? You should also include an explanation of what actually happens. Just saying that you're "unable" to do it is a terrible and unhelpful description.

Comment: first learn what modal is, because `window.open` open a new website on tab however modal is an div appearing in front.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this:

View:
<div id="DemoModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Jquery:
function OpenModel(Title, Body, modalsize) {

        $("#DemoModal").find(".modal-content").html(Body).after(function (e) {
            if (modalsize == null) {
                modalsize = 'modal-lg'
            }
            $("#DemoModal").find(".modal-dialog").attr('class', 'modal-dialog ' + modalsize + '');
            $("#DemoModal").find(" ").html(Title);
            $("#DemoModal").modal("show");
        })

    }

And when you need to call pop up then simply pass:

 OpenModel("", data, '')
in jquery.
```